# How do I search for all unsubscribed e-mails across any/all groups

Tags: civimail, unsubscribe

Newbie question: How do I search for all unsubscribed e-mails across any/all groups?

I would also like to mark e-mail addresses if they're unsubscribed from an imported list. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what version of Civi you are on (I'm on 4.7.9), but take a looking under Reports > Mailing Reports > Mailing Detail Report - I think this will give you a good solid list to work with (see attached screen shot for available columns) - on the filters tab you also have the option to filter by group.

[image]

Hope this helps!
Tamar

Answer (score 1):

I just tried a few things, and I don't think this is possible out of the box!  If you're a coder, you could write a custom search to do this.  Or you could query the MySQL database.  The `civicrm_group_contact` folder has the info you want in the `status` field.